# Amazon EC2 Instance IDs - Why XOR?

Tags: amazon-ec2, obfuscation, instance, xor

According to [Guy Rosen](http://www.jackofallclouds.com/2009/09/anatomy-of-an-amazon-ec2-resource-id/) and [RightScale](http://blog.rightscale.com/2009/10/05/amazon-usage-estimates/) the Amazon EC2 instance IDs contain two XORs against the first and second half of the "Inner ID" and all three against their own constant.

I understand that we won't know exactly why Amazon does this. However, from a general perspective, has anyone implemented or seen this sort of XOR and why would this XOR be implemented?

Is the only purpose to help obfuscate the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obfuscation via a straightforward binary operator seems a little silly considering how little it apparently worked to prevent people from figuring it out. I would assume that Mr. Rosen stumbled across one possible use for it, the only other I can think of is some form of resource tracking.

Of course, until someone from Amazon tells us this will all be pure idle speculation.

Comment: Can you explain how the XOR could be for resource tracking?

Comment: @Rob Olmos - not without a great deal more understanding of how Amazon has their hardware/software set up. It just struck me as curious that parts of the ID were always even, then I realized these instances are being created and destroyed often enough that tracking them might be useful. I'm sure using that information a clever 'mark for deletion / as blank / for cleanup/shutdown/whatever' system might be set up for automated processes.

Comment: I'm asking in a general sense, I understand we don't know exactly why Amazon does it but instead if others have implemented/seen XOR like this and why.

Comment: @Rob Olmos - I've used a similar technique while programming ASM for RISC chipsets, it gave me extremely fine-grained control over every byte of memory.